# Port is not Listed

Tags: java, linux, rxtx

I want to do serial communication with the USB GSM Modem in linux. I have used the following code. but portList.hashElements is returning as false. I have used RXTX librarry 2.1.7 version. please help me.

**code**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import gnu.io.*;

public class SimpleWrite {

static Enumeration portList;
static CommPortIdentifier portId;
static String messageString = "Hello, world!\n";
static SerialPort serialPort;
static OutputStream outputStream;
private static SerialPort p;

public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchPortException {


    Enumeration ports = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();
    System.out.println("start: "+ ports.hasMoreElements());
    while(ports.hasMoreElements())
    {
        CommPortIdentifier port = (CommPortIdentifier) ports.nextElement();
        System.out.print(port.getName() + " -> " + port.getCurrentOwner() + " -> ");
        switch(port.getPortType())
        {
            case CommPortIdentifier.PORT_PARALLEL:
                System.out.println("parell");
            break;
            case CommPortIdentifier.PORT_SERIAL:
                System.out.println("serial");
            try {
                p = (SerialPort) port.open("SimpleWrite", 1000);
                int baudRate = 57600; // 57600bps
                p.setSerialPortParams(
                        baudRate,
                        SerialPort.DATABITS_8,
                        SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,
                        SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);
            } catch (PortInUseException e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            } catch (UnsupportedCommOperationException e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("stop");
}
}
```

**The Output is:**

> ## Stable Library
>
> Native lib Version = RXTX-2.1-7
>   Java lib Version   = RXTX-2.1-7
>   start: **false**
>   stop
>   Experimental:  JNI_OnLoad called .

System.out.println("start: "+ ports.hasMoreElements()); is printing as **false**. please help me. thanking you

Comment: looks like RXTX library for LTP and COM ports, not for USB.

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention to device naming, because linux do not recognise any naming pattern.

Maybe my answer can help:

[serial port identification with java on ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18669379/serial-port-identification-with-java-on-ubuntu/21567949#21567949)

Answer (score 0):

Similiar bug for me under Ubuntu 14.04. Port is not listed.
Found workaround by running program as root.